# How to bypass sql connection error with simple msgbox

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Preparing the connection check to the SQL sever, which gives me below error if not in our group network its obsoletely fine but simple msgbox sufficient for me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQSGN.png)

```vb
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()
         
    Dim Cn As ADODB.connection
    Dim server_name As String
    Dim database_name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
          
    server_name = "192.168.x.xxx\SQLEXPRESS"
    database_name = "ABC_System"
    User_ID = "xx"
    Password = "12345"
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Tbl_anb"
    'SQLStr = "dbo.Tbl_wid"
     
    Set Cn = New ADODB.connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & server_name & ";Database=" & database_name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
    
    If Cn.State = 1 Then
    Debug.Print "Connected!"
    MsgBox "Connected"
    Else
    MsgBox "Not Connected"
    
    
End If
```

Comment: You can use On error resume next. BTW you are using a very old driver. It is 20+ years old. You could instead use {SQL Server Native Client 11.0}

Comment: Could you help where to add error handling

Comment: If you don't prefix my name with @ or not comment under a message of mine, then I wouldn't get the notification, thus wouldn't see it at all.  Just FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is modified version with On error:

```
Dim Cn As ADODB.connection
Dim server_name As String
Dim database_name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set ws = ActiveSheet

      
server_name = "192.168.x.xxx\SQLEXPRESS"
database_name = "ABC_System"
User_ID = "xx"
Password = "12345"
SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Tbl_anb"
'SQLStr = "dbo.Tbl_wid"
 
Set Cn = New ADODB.connection

On error resume next 

Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & server_name & ";Database=" & database_name & _
";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

on error Goto 0

If Cn.State = 1 Then
Debug.Print "Connected!"
MsgBox "Connected"
Else
MsgBox "Not Connected"
end if
```